# Three.js import blender object

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, blender

I'm trying to import blender scene to three.js with ObjectLoader() function. I want this to be as easy as possible, without animation just objects with right texture and colour in right place. Unfortunately three.js documentation is not a friendly place for newbies. So far I managed to draw every object from scene but every object is in different colour, plane lacks its texture and they are all in wrong places. What am I doing wrong? Here is my .js code:

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
var WIDTH  = window.innerWidth;
var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    initCamera();
    initLights();
    initRenderer();
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function initCamera() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10);
    camera.position.set(0, 3.5, 5);
   camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

function initRenderer() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
   renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function initLights() {
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    scene.add(light);
}

var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load('./city.json', function(loadedObj) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(loadedObj);
    var plane = loadedObj.getObjectByName("plane");
    var building1 = loadedObj.getObjectByName("building1");
    var building2 = loadedObj.getObjectByName("building2");
    var building3 = loadedObj.getObjectByName("building3");
    var building4 = loadedObj.getObjectByName("building4");
    var building5 = loadedObj.getObjectByName("building5");
    var building6 = loadedObj.getObjectByName("building6");
    var building7 = loadedObj.getObjectByName("building7");
    var building8 = loadedObj.getObjectByName("building8");


    scene.add(loadedObj);
    console.log(building1);
    console.log(building2);
    console.log(building3);
    console.log(building4);
    console.log(building5);
    console.log(building6);
    console.log(building7);
    console.log(building8);
});

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
render();
```

Is it possible that there is problem with way of exporting from blender not with code?

EDIT: Sorry about that, here's my city.json file
[city.json](https://github.com/dachoj/blender/blob/master/city.json)

Comment: Hard for us to know without seeing what your `city.json` file

Comment: In the three.js exporter settings, have you selected things like Scene, Material, Textures, Hierarchy, etc.? I'm not sure which of those you'll want here, but as your `city.json` file appears no contain only geometry, you probably aren't exporting everything you need. Including the JSON and `.blend` file would help. You might also want to try other formats like OBJ, FBX, or glTF, which are supported by three.js using different loaders.

Comment: Edited and added city.json file